# Difference between okhttp fastFallback in okhttp4 vs okhttp5

Tags: ip, okhttp, ipv6, ipv4

Okhttp introduced fastFallback in version 4 and then in version 5, they have introduced that again naming it as HappyEyeballs, can share some share the difference between the two implementations ?

In Okhttp4: https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-ok-http-client/fast-fallback/

In Okhttp5: https://square.github.io/okhttp/changelogs/changelog/#version-500-alpha4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simpler than that. The URL for the docs is wrong; it should say 5.x and we OkHttp maintainers need to fix that.